# Readmore.js Implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm implementing Readmore.js on a website.

Links to Readmore:

- http://www.fao.org/fileadmin/scripts/jquery/Readmore.js-master/demo.html
- https://github.com/jedfoster/Readmore.js

What I want is to show "Read more..." buttons and collapse text only on mobile devices. Say width less 640px.

So I've applied a condition if width of screen less than 640px just then apply: .readmore();

Code below:

```
    (function resize(){
    if (document.body.clientWidth<=640) {
      $('.quote-heading').readmore({
      speed: 75,
      lessLink: '<a href="#">Less</a>',
      moreLink:'<a href="#">Read more...</a>',
      collapsedHeight: 100,
      blockProcessed:function(element,collapsable){
          console.log(element);
      }
        });
    }
    if (document.body.clientWidth>640){
      $('.quote-heading').readmore('destroy');
    }
    })();
```

The problem is if you resize your screen more than 640px "Read more..." buttons still there. Only if your screen more than 640px and your reload your page just then the second condition is met. 
Btw I tried to invoke function "onresize" event but error pops up saying that .readmore() is not a function.

Comment: You could use CSS to hide the anchor tags? Might be abit lighter than using JS to check the window width every time the window changes size etc.

Answer (score 1):

Give this code ago...

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var $reader = $('.quote-heading').readmore({
    speed: 75,
    lessLink: '<a href="#">Less</a>',
    moreLink: '<a href="#">Read more...</a>',
    collapsedHeight: 100
  });

  if ($(window).width() < 640) {
    $reader.readmore('destroy');
  }
}).trigger('resize');
```

A working example can be found here: https://jsfiddle.net/o6cz8e1h/